# Using a global lua_State* variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, lua, global-variables

I want to use a global lua_State* variable in my program, initializing it through a initLua() function and use it to run some Lua functions from main(). When I try it, the Lua code simply won't run. In the future, I want to use an array of Lua states to implement multithreading, where each thread has it's own Lua state.

When I initialize the Lua state inside main(), everything works fine. I'm running W10.

inside cfg.lua:

```lua
function teste()
    return 10;
end
```

in C++, used to set the global state variable *L:

```cpp
void initLua(lua_State *L) {    
    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    luaL_dofile(L, "./cfg.lua");    
}
```

In `main()`, int `foo(L)` calls the `teste()` function from Lua, and the result is printed.

`10` should be printed, but nothing happens when the state variable is being initialized outside `main()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I strongly recommend keeping your Lua state local. It's a lot easier to read code if you can see from the arguments that a function uses the Lua state.

If you really need to make the Lua state global, then `initLua` should not have any parameters. Your problem is caused by the fact that you assign to the parameter `L` and not a global variable.

Even if your Lua state was local, `initLua` still should not take a parameter. It could just make a local `lua_State *` variable and return that.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I'll try again and some back with the results.